# Associative array can't echo data from input form

Tags: php, html

I insert data to the array from an input box. But I don't know why I can't print the associative array. I can only echo the latest data from the input box. I want to add data to the array and echo it every time I write to the input box.

```
    <?php
    $part_insert_message = "";

    $inserted_parts = array();

    session_start();

    $part_inserted_id;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $part_inserted_id = $_POST['arrdata'];
    $inserted_parts[$part_inserted_id] = $part_inserted_id; 
    echo sizeof($inserted_parts);
    // store session data
    $_SESSION['views']= $inserted_parts;
    $part_insert_message = "ID: " . $part_inserted_id;
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<div>
<h2>Part</h2>
<form action="array_session_example.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
Array Data: <input type="text" name="arrdata"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php echo $part_insert_message;
    foreach($inserted_parts as $key => $value){
        echo $key;
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new array every time, and then adding that to the session.  You'll need to check if an array has already been stored, and if it has add to that.

```
    $inserted_parts = array();

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views']) && is_array($_SESSION['views'])) 
        $inserted_parts = $_SESSION['views'];
```